# SelectedIndexChanged not firing in asp.net usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, selectedindexchanged, obout

.net 4.0, ASP.net, vb.net.

I've got a usercontrol that is using an obout combo box.  The obout is a cascading combobox that has 3 levels to it.  when something it selected from the third level of the combobox, it is suppose to fire off a selectedIndexChanged event.  This happens the first time that I select the usercontrol.  The problem is if i want to go back and select something different.  The selectedIndexChanged doesn't fire.  I've set breakpoints and the

```
AddHandler ComboBox3.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged
```

runs just like it did the first time i select the usercontrol.  But the selectedIndex just doesn't fire the second go around.  Was wondering what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the selectedIndexChanged that is not firing

```
Sub ComboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ComboBoxItemEventArgs)
    Dim Oc As New Dempsey.ClassIndex_Controller
    Dim O As New Dempsey.ClassIndex
    oClassIndexs = Oc.GetClassIndexData(CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedValue))
    For Each O In oClassIndexs
    Next
    ClassSearchResults = o
    RaiseEvent myClassificationSearch(oClassIndexs, e)
End Sub
```

I'll add whatever other code you might want to see... but didn't want to make the post too long.

thanks
shannon

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
some more info.. as mentioned above, this is a cascading combobox.  So combobox1 has values of say 1,2,3, Combobox 2 gets it's data filtered depending on what you select on combobox1.

Well.. i've noticed that if i select 1 in combobox 1 the first time through, things work as expected.  If on the second round i select something other than 1 in combobox1, the event fires.  However, if i select 1 in combobox 1 on the second round through, the event does not fire.

This is not the way i need it to work because it could be that the second time through, i need to select the same value in combobox1 but a different value in combobox2.  Any idea what i can do to get around this... since it would appear that it's working the way it should.

i mention it above.. but i'm using an Obout combox control
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt, when your dropdown selection changed, your dropdown again `binded` somewhere, perhaps in the `page load` event and it lost the chance for the `SelectedIndex Changed` event to be fired.

Comment: ok.. not real sure about that.  The addhandler is added in a pageload event in the usercontrol.  when i step through the code i've placed a breakpoint at the addhandler.  it is getting fired on the second pass through the usercontrol.  do you have any other ideas or maybe i'm not understanding you correctly